# Dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 13.04, windows-10

I'm a new Ubuntu user and I just installed it on my Lenovo Flex 15 laptop. The issue is grub does not list Windows 10 as an option, it lists Windows 8.

I can boot into either OS (Ubuntu or Windows 10) though I need to press the "Novo" button to load the Boot Menu. From here I can select either OS - Ubuntu appears as the ATA listing, Windows as the Boot Manager.

Here is my current Boot info from the BIOS:

1. Boot Option Menu - ATA  HDD; Network Boot; Windows Boot
2. The BIOS setup InsydeH20 Setup Utility:

   - Configuration menu: Power Beep and Deep s3 function are Disabled.

All options including USB Legacy are enabled. The system does not offer a secure startup option - I read these suggestions elsewhere on the forum.

- Boot Mode menu: Boot Mode - Legacy Support; Boot Priority - Legacy first; USB Boot - enabled; EFI - Windows Boot Manager (ST500LM000); Legacy - ATA HDD (ST500LM000), Network Boot - Realtek PXE...

If I turn off the Legacy Support boot mode, Windows 10 loads without issue. With the option enabled the Grub menu loads.

Grub options: Ubuntu, Advanced Options for Ubuntu, 2 separate Mem Test options, Windows Recovery Environment, Windows 8 Loader (on /dev/sda5).

Is it possible to update grub to include the entry for Windows 10?

When I installed Ubuntu, I chose the option for the side-by-side installation. I did not previously partition the hard drive but configured the storage size during the install.

There are a few posts on the forum that offer some complex solutions. I hope that someone else has experience with the Lenovo laptop that offers some encouraging news or suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Thanks for taking the time to write a high-quality question :)

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, Win 10 is installed in UEFI mode, but Ubuntu is installed in Legacy mode? If so, that's your issue.

Comment: Also, just for the future, installing both Windows and Ubuntu in Legacy mode is the sure-fire way to get it to work OOTB. Once you start messing with UEFI *(which I absoluteley **HATE** btw, things can and will go downhill... although I'm sure @KazWolfe will disagree with me)*